# What is the difference between node clustering and network community detection?

Tags: self-study, clustering, graph-theory, networks

Node clustering algorithms in which we attempt to determine dense regions of the graph based on edge behaviour(either be a distance value or a similarity value). The more similar nodes come together and form a cluster.

Communities in a network are the dense groups of the nodes, which are tightly coupled to each other inside the group and loosely coupled to
the rest of the nodes in the network. Community detection methods mean, find out the tightly coupled nodes group in a network.

My understanding is node clustering and network community detection are same(Please correct me if I am wrong). Is there any difference between them?

Please note that **Graph clustering** and **Node clustering** are different concepts.

**Graph Clustering**: We have a (possibly large) number of graphs which need to be clustered based on their underlying
structural behaviour. This problem is challenging because of the need to
match the structures of the underlying graphs(K-clique is NP-Complete) and use these structures for clustering purposes.

For more details please refer the paper: [A Survey of Clustering Algorithms for Graph Data](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4419-6045-0_9)

Any discussions are appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between graph clustering and community detection methods?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15824/what-is-the-difference-between-graph-clustering-and-community-detection-methods)

Comment: No. Graph clustering and node clustering are different concepts. In graph clustering,  the clustering is based on the structure.